# start ping www.google.si closes my cmd window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

I need to open cmd window multiple times from a cmd window. Site address or ip would change, so i can ping router, pc, google,.. The problem is when i issue this command it closes my original window i can open more than i window like that. I have set the cmd windows to go to a menu to choose other options after that. I do have some parameters set, but its not working with or without them.

```
start ping 192.168.0.1
```

If nothing else, could i open .bat file with this command and change address and parameters somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Not really sure when i solved the original cmd window closing but here is the code:

```
start cmd /c "color 0a & title ping %ip% %l% %t% %n% & cls & ping %ip% %l% %t% %n% & echo. & pause >nul | set /p = Press any key to EXIT.."
```

I used /c to issue more commands in a row. Now i can open cmd windows without getting main one closed, use parameters i want each time and keep it opened after it finnishes its job.

Answer (score 2):

try to use a bat file with this code

```
start cmd /k PING TARGET_IP1 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL 
start cmd /k PING TARGET_IP2 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL 
start cmd /k PING TARGET_IP3 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
```

- /k stay the window open
- >nul is like @echo off
- -w 5000 is just the timeout in miliseconds

Comment: your `>NUL` is meaningless. It redirects the output of the `start` command to NUL, but that's empty anyways.

Comment: this does not help. with start command i wish to open another cmd window to constantly ping address, and return to the menu to choose what other adresses to ping this way. `start cmd /k ping %ip%` gives back "General failure" at every ping sent and closes my original window. Is it possible to set a avriable and give it to another .bat file?